# How to retrieve the data from the sever and displaying it in a page?

Tags: php, wp-query, database, wpdb, html

I am a newbie to Wordpress and php. I have a table in my database which keeps on getting updated by the users. I just wanted to write a code which gets the information from the table and display some of the information from the table in one of my page. For that purpose, I am using the following code.

```
<?php


$number_rows= $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->daviddgl_wp1.SaveContactForm7_7" );
$x=1;
while ($x<$number_rows) {
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ticket, name,email FROM $wpdb->daviddgl_wp1.SaveContactForm7_7 WHERE id = $x"
echo $results;
$x++;
}

?>
```

It gives me the following error.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in
>   /home/daviddgl/public_html/wp-content/themes/panoramic-child/cleanphppage.php
>   on line 38

which I was not able to figure it out.

### How to correct this??

Kindly note that, in future I may style the output, that is I may want to use css to style the table which I am creating using the while loop.

Thank you for helping!!!

Comment: I actually addressed this in a recent inquiry and found the solution. Here is the link. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/254193/how-can-i-call-a-row-of-user-specific-data-from-a-custom-table-added-to-the-wp-d

Answer (score 2):

So in this case, the problem is that your line right before the `echo` call is incomplete:

```
$number_rows= $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->daviddgl_wp1.SaveContactForm7_7" );
$x=1;
while ($x<$number_rows) {
    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ticket, name,email FROM $wpdb->daviddgl_wp1.SaveContactForm7_7 WHERE id = $x");
    print_r($results);
    $x++;
}
```

(You're missing the closing bracket and semi-column)

Note also that your echo will not work here, since $results will be an array. You'll probably want to use var_dump or print_r - like I did in the above example.

Hope this helps!